# Как автоматически перезапустить Gulp при изменении gulpfile.js?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm, gulp-watch

Хочу найти аналог gulp-watch который бы перезапускал gulp при правках в самом gulpfile.js.

Нагуглить пока смог только такое решение
https://codepen.io/ScavaJripter/post/how-to-watch-the-same-gulpfile-js-with-gulp

Есть еще какие-то проверенные варианты?

Это решение у меня не заработало корректно (при обновлении gulpfile.js файл style.css не пересобирается). 
Может где ошибся в коде? 
Или есть более простые и надежные альтернативы? 
Упрощенный пример реализации в gulpfile.js

```
/****************************************************************
Подключение зависимостей 
*****************************************************************/


const gulp        = require('gulp');     //gulp локально
const sass        = require('gulp-sass');
const watch       = require('gulp-watch');  //перезапуск задач по обновлению файлов (штатный watch может глючить при добавлении нового файла)
const sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const concat      = require('gulp-concat'); // Конкатенация файлов
const minifyCSS   = require('gulp-csso');
const plumber     = require('gulp-plumber');
const notify      = require("gulp-notify");




/****************************************************************
CSS
*****************************************************************/


    gulp.task('sass', function(){ 

        gulp.src(['_sass/**/*+(.sass|.scss)']) 

            .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError)) 
            .pipe(concat('style.css'))  
            .pipe(minifyCSS({restructure: false}))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));


    });


/****************************************************************
Перезапуск задач по обновлению файлов 
*****************************************************************/


gulp.slurped = false; // step 1

    gulp.task("watch", function(){
        if(!gulp.slurped){ // step 2
            gulp.watch("gulpfile.js", ["default"]);
            gulp.watch('_sass/**/*+(.sass|.scss)', ['sass']); 
            gulp.slurped = true; // step 3
        }
    });



/****************************************************************
ИТОГОВЫЕ ЗАДАЧИ
*****************************************************************/


// gulp
gulp.task('default', [
    'sass',
    'watch'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

создайте по логике- 
отслеживаем watch-eм сам gulp файл и если он изменился, то закрываем  watch отслеживание и запускаем весь файл задач gulp...
Либо создай таск ещё одним файлом, который будет отслеживать меняющийся gulp файл, и если он изменился, то перезапусать таск
Не проверял, но хорошая идея- надо будет и себе такое сделать.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. Вы не могли бы дать простейший пример кода для такого решения? Я его доработаю, отлажу и пришлю вам обратно результат.